# events not working in my widget inside Custom cell of GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt

I am adding a panel with Google visualization charts in my celltable .

like this

```
 public class CustomCell extends AbstractCell<VerticalPanel> {

Panel panel;

@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
        VerticalPanel chartContainer, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
if ( chartContainer == null ) return;

    GWTWidget myGwtWidget = new GWTWidget();
    myGwtWidget.getPan().add(chartContainer);
    sb.appendHtmlConstant(myGwtWidget.getElement().getString());

}
```

It shows my verticalPanel which have the charts , But the charts tooltips gone ,

I then tried onBrowse as below , But it forces me to remove @Override..
and things not working ..

Any idea , where i am wrong

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(
    Context context,
    Element parent,
    VerticalPanel value,
    NativeEvent event,
    ValueUpdater<VerticalPanel> valueUpdater) {

  // Let AbstractCell handle the keydown event.
  super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);

  // Handle the click event.
  if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
    // Ignore clicks that occur outside of the outermost element.
    EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
    if (parent.getFirstChildElement().isOrHasChild(Element.as(eventTarget))) {
      Window.alert("ss");
    }
  }
}
```

Here I am adding chart in my celltable ..  (this custCell is instance of the above custCell class)

```
        Column<Contact, VerticalPanel> graphColumn = new Column<Contact, VerticalPanel>(custCell) {
                @Override
                public VerticalPanel getValue(Contact object) {

                    ColumnChart pie = new ColumnChart(createTable(object.getEnglish(), object.getMaths()), createOptions());

                    pie.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
                    VerticalPanel vpChart = new VerticalPanel();
                    vp.add(vpChart);
                    vpChart.add(pie);
                    vpChart.setWidth("300px");

                    return vpChart;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

The moment you call `.getElement().getString()`, you get a plain HTML with no functionality.

I don't know what GWTWidget is supposed to do, but it won't do it after you call `.getElement().getString()`.

Comment: GWTWidget is just a simple composite with a panel in it.and this chartContainer is having a googleVisualization chart in it[which is appearing fine inside celltable but has lost tooltips] .. If i dont use .getElement().getString().,  The panel/chart wont even appear in my celltable, Can you suggest any solution

Comment: I have not used this API yet. Maybe you can try to inject charts after a CellTable is rendered. Or use something else instead of CellTable (e.g. FlexTable).

Comment: thanks , but the issue is general , not related to this API. As you mentioned that what ever is GWTWidget it will not work after .getElement().getString(),  I tried to add a simple Label here[like myGwtWidget.getPan().add(new Label("test"));],but If i remove .getElement().getString(), A Simple Label will not appear even. So can you suggest displaying a LABEL inside celltable without  doing .getElement().getString()

Comment: just edited my question , showing where i am adding this chart in the celltable

Comment: You can display any HTML inside a cell, and calling `.getElement().getString()` is not a problem. The problem is that it simply renders this HTML, but there will be no interactive functionality that this widget had before .getString() was called. Since Label has no such functionality, it will work fine.

Comment: Try to use SafeHtmlCell instead of extending AbstractCell.